# KDE Neon randomly freezes, can't access Virtual Terminal, have to restart system

Tags: linux, kde, freeze, plasma5

I am experiencing an issue that makes my screen go black for one second, then it goes back normal, i see everything i was doing on the screen, I can move my mouse cursor, I steill hear audio playing in background, but I can't literally interact with the screen in any other way than moving the mouse cursor; I can't open a new terminal, and I can't even get to my Virtual Terminal using the keyboard shortcut. The only way I can exit this situation is to force restart my laptop pressing the button.
This usually happens randomly. I can use the computer fluently for hours and all of a sudden this happens, but I saw that usually the problem happens when I navigate tabs on mozilla or I am running some snaps (tried to reinstall the snaps but the problem is still showing)

**Some system infos:**
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.4
Kernel Version: 5.19.0-40 generic
Graphics Platform: X11
Qt: 5.15.9
KDE Frameworks: 5.105.0
kf5-config: 1.0

**HARDWARE**
[image: lshw]
[image: lspci]

Comment: Please [edit] and also post hardware specifications, namely graphics.

Comment: Done, ty, tell me if i need to specify something more (i'm a linux newbie)

Comment: I was expecting some Nvidia running with the open-source drivers instead of the proprietary ones. Not the case here, you have AMD so all the required drivers are already in use. You may want to update UEFI and play with the IOMMU settings and perhaps others.